# Creating a UITableView object crashes in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am making a to-do app in Swift, and I am trying to display the tasks using a **UITableView**. Users add a task, and press "Done". The **UITableView** is brought back to the front, and the app crashes. Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil) //crashes on this line
    cell.textLabel!.text = taskMgr.tasksArray[indexPath.row].name
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = taskMgr.tasksArray[indexPath.row].desc

    return cell
}
```

Funny enough, this line works fine in another very similar app I quickly created. Could anyone please point me in the right direction? I am happy to add more detail if necessary.

Comment: Why are you not reusing the cell with cellidentifier?

Comment: You really don't need to fly blind.  When the app crashes, look at the stack, check for an error message.  If the app is blowing past the actual error, add a symbolic breakpoint on all exceptions.  If you see an exception being thrown, print the exception.  Before embarking into development, you need to learn the basics on how to use the debugging tools to get more information.  It's a lot faster than posting to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use reuse identifier

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tblSwift.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

With Detail Title

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -&gt; UITableViewCell! {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    cell!.textLabel.text = self.names[indexPath.row]
    cell!.detailTextLabel.text = self.emails[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: wher does "cell" come from? I am trying to do the same but with a custom tableview with sections like the one in the OS Settings, where you can have a list of options with another list of WiFi spots nearby inside.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.lblText.text  = "Testing"
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code to take advantage of the performance of a UITableView. Your cells can be re-used instead of re-created each time they are displayed on screen.

To do this, you should remove the init method call of UITableViewCell. Instead replace it with:
[dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:)

New in iOS 6, the pattern is to register a TableViewCell subclass with the tableview with the reuse identifier. Then you can easily grab a re-usable cell with dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:forindexPath:

In `viewDidLoad` or somewhere before the tableview datasource/delegate methods are called, you should make a call to register your cell subclass.
[registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:)

For you, in Swift, you'll want to call:

```
tableview.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, identifier:"MyReuseIdentifier")
// note there is also a method to register nibs
```

Then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
tableView.dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Comment: My program still crashes on `tableView.dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyReuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)`.

Comment: is there any error message or log? Is 'tableView' or indexPath nil by any chance(this would be really odd)?